# Standardizing regression coefficients in the case of Total Least Squares Regression

Tags: regression, standardization, total-least-squares

So I know that there exits a method to standardize regression coefficients by simply multiplying them with the ratio of the standard deviations of the two variables. I'm wondering if this holds true for Total Least Squares Regression as well. That is, could I simply multiply the ration of the standard deviations and get standardized TLS regression coefficients as well? If not, could someone recommend a way to get standardized coefficients in this case? Thanks!

Comment: In ordinary regression, the standardized coefficients relate the standardized regressor values to the standardized response values.  Could you describe for us what "standardized TLS regression coefficients" are intended to represent?

Comment: So basically I am performing both regular/non-TLS regression and TLS regression on a dataset. For the regular regression, I am reporting  standardized betas so that all my estimates range from -1 to 1, and I was hoping to do the same for the Total Least Squares regressions. So, I am looking for a way to standardize what I report for the two kinds of regressions, to make them as comparable as they can be. Thanks!

Comment: Standardized regression coefficients are not guaranteed to lie between $-1$ and $1,$ except when there is just a single regressor.  What, then, is the objective in reporting standardized betas?